# write under Underbrace

Tags: pdftex, underbrace

how do I write according to the image in LaTeX?

[image: Underbrace]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the one you looking for???

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
'$\underbrace{1}_{\textsf{$k$-\'{e}sima}}$'
\end{document}
```